# Using R convert data.frame to simple vector

Tags: r

I have this `data.frame`:

```
v.row <- data.frame(
  X1 = 177,
  X2 = 165,
  X3 = 177,
  X4 = 177,
  X5 = 177,
  X6 = 177,
  X7 = 145,
  X8 = 132,
  X9 = 126,
  X10 = 132,
  X11 = 132,
  X12 = 132,
  X13 = 126,
  X14 = 120,
  X15 = 145,
  X16 = 167,
  X17 = 167,
  X18 = 167,
  X19 = 167,
  X20 = 165,
  X21 = 177,
  X22 = 177,
  X23 = 177,
  X24 = 177
)
```

I would remove all row and column names in order to get a simple `vector`. But the `as.vector` function doesn't work (it returns a `data.frame`).

```
> as.vector(v.row)
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24
57 177 165 177 177 177 177 145 132 126 132 132 132 126 120 145 167 167 167 167 165 177 177 177 177
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

see `?unlist`

> Given a list structure x, unlist simplifies it to produce a vector
>   which contains all the atomic components which occur in x.

```
unlist(v.row)
[1] 177 165 177 177 177 177 145 132 126 132 132 132 126 120 145 167 167 167
       167 165 177 177 177 177
```

**EDIT**

You can do it with `as.vector` also, but you need to provide the correct mode:

```
 as.vector(v.row,mode='numeric')
 [1] 177 165 177 177 177 177 145 132 126 132 132 132 126 120 145 167 167
      167 167 165 177 177 177 177
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a note on the second part of agstudy's answer:

```
df <- data.frame(1:10) 
as.vector(df, mode="integer") #Error

as.vector(df[[1]],mode="integer") #Works; 
as.vector(df[[1]]) #Also works
```

i.e., apparently you have to select the list element from the dataframe even though there's only 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

I had this data frame from csv

```
x <- as.numeric(dataframe$column_name)
```

worked great. (same with `dataframe[3]`, 3 being my column index didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

[`pull()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html).

With the [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package (part of `tidyverse`), you can use [`pull()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `as.matrix` with `as.vector` like this:

```r
as.vector(as.matrix(v.row))
#>  [1] 177 165 177 177 177 177 145 132 126 132 132 132 126 120 145 167 167 167 167
#> [20] 165 177 177 177 177
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>